# in-memory-cache of specific files from NFS

Tags: nfs, cache

I have some diskless machines and they mount a disk through NFS4. I want the machines to maintain a cache of specific files in their own memory. The machines don't modify the files and only read them occasionally but I need to change the list of cached files sometimes. How can I achieve it?

Comment: How about a ramdisk that can be out of sync with the network file system instead of caching?

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify which files are cached by the [cachefilesd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cachefilesd), it simply caches the files used by the system. You can tune how the cache works by setting parameters in cachefilesd.conf but basically all you 
get to do is turn it on using the `fsc` option to mount and the system does the rest.

Red Hat have a good [write up](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-fscache.html) on it.